# DynamicVariable inside Future

Tags: scala, concurrency, thread-local-storage

There as an example code below that is an abstraction of the code that is believed to causing an issue very seldomly.
Issue means even though a new future is constucted `currentSession.value.isDefined` is true.

```
object databaseImpl {

  private val currentSession = new DynamicVariable[Option[String]](None)

  def withSessionExecute[T](f: String => T): T = {
    val session = "dummy"
    checkNoSessionInThread()
    currentSession.withValue(Option(session)) {
      f(session)
    }
  }

  private def checkNoSessionInThread(): Unit = {
    if (currentSession.value.isDefined) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Currentsession has already a value :(")   
    }
  }
}
```

Example usage

```
Future {databaseImpl.withSessionExecute( session => session)}
```

What could cause a DynamicVariable in a class used inside a Future to have a value prior it being set inside the Future?
Can a future switch threads while executing?

Answer (score 1):

`DynamicVariable` implementations in Scala use thread-local space. If you read the documentation on thread-local values, you will see that the `DynamicVariable` is associated with the current thread. When the thread spawns another thread, the thread-local space is duplicated into the new thread, with whatever values have been bound. For this and several more reasons, `DynamicVariable` is almost never a good solution to use.

`Future`s depend on the execution context in which they run. Some execution contexts may well be able to move tasks between threads. Read the [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) on execution contexts and futures in Scala.

Comment: Your wrote "move tasks between threads" - tasks there means the calculation of results inside a Future right?

Comment: A `Future` that has a `blocking` block in it may be rescheduled, depending on the execution context. You will have to study the execution context source code to determine how it handles this. I don't believe the default execution context currently implements thread hopping.